# setup:di:compile - Warning: Narrowing occurred during type inference

Tags: magento2, php, php-7, exception, setup-di-compile

I'm getting this error when running `php -f bin/magento setup:di:compile`

> Warning: Narrowing occurred during type inference

Does anyone know how to fix it?

> `php -f bin/magento setup:di:compile -vvv Compilation was started.
>   Proxies code generation... 0/7 [>---------------------------]   0% < 1
>   sec 34.0 Proxies code generation... 1/7 [====>-----------------------]
>   14% 1 sec 36.0 MiRepositories code generation... 1/7
>   [====>-----------------------]  14% 1 sec 36.0 MiB`
>
> **[Exception]   Warning: Narrowing occurred during type inference.
>   Please file a bug report    on bugs.php.net in
>   vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 444**
>
> Exception trace:  () at
>   vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61
>   Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler() at
>   vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php:444
>   include() at vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php:444
>   Composer\Autoload\includeFile() at
>   vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php:322
>   Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass() at n/a:n/a
>   spl_autoload_call() at n/a:n/a
>   class_exists() at
>   setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Reader/ClassesScanner.php:122
>   Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Reader\ClassesScanner->includeClasses()
>   at
>   setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Reader/ClassesScanner.php:108
>   Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Reader\ClassesScanner->extract() at
>   setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Reader/ClassesScanner.php:79
>   Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Reader\ClassesScanner->getList() at
>   setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/App/Task/Operation/RepositoryGenerator.php:61
>   Magento\Setup\Module\Di\App\Task\Operation\RepositoryGenerator->doOperation()
>   at setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/App/Task/Manager.php:56
>   Magento\Setup\Module\Di\App\Task\Manager->process() at
>   setup/src/Magento/Setup/Console/Command/DiCompileCommand.php:205
>   Magento\Setup\Console\Command\DiCompileCommand->execute() at
>   vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:242
>   Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at
>   vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:842
>   Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at
>   vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:193
>   Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at
>   vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php:104
>   Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->doRun() at
>   vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:117
>   Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at
>   bin/magento:23
>
> setup:di:compile

In vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php line 443~445

```
{
    include $file;
}
```

If I run `php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production` it will show this code

```
Enabled maintenance mode
Starting compilation
Something went wrong while compiling generated code. See the error log for details.
Command returned non-zero exit code:
`/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/bin/php -f bin/magento setup:di:compile`
```

Comment: It seems like there is some error in some files you created recently. It could be any kind of error. As you may see that there is no line 444 in ClassLoader.php. So please provide us more of what you did recently.

Comment: from 2.2.0 upgraded to 2,2.2 . the file line 444 is include $file; <-not wrong. how can i fix it,please help...

Comment: i used this php magento deploy:mode:set production getting need to run php bin/magento setup:di:compile

Comment: I updated in the post ~please check

Comment: can you show the code in  /home/xxxx/public_html/vendor/composer/ClassLoader. php on line 444

Comment: updated in the post ,please check

Comment: just remove var folder from your root and try again

Comment: and if i php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production will show this code , please check the post ,thank you

Comment: remove var folder but can't